# Are universal links supposed to redirect app to app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I want to know about the behavior of universal links. My confusion stems from the documentation Apple provides for the behavior of universal links: "iOS users can tap a link to your website and get seamlessly redirected to your installed app without going through Safari". (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

However, when clicking a universal link in my application, I'm seeing a redirect to safari then a message, "Open in the Spotify App," to app instead of app to app like the documentation suggests.

Some background of how the universal link is being clicked or tapped: I have an application that I created that I'm using a web view (WKWebView and UIWebView) that when clicked redirects to a specified url. I'm also using openUrl:withOptions:completionHandler:. I want to know what happens when a user clicks a universal link that is in the web view that I created.

Are universal supposed to go directly app to app? Or, it is expected to go from app to safari (with a message saying "Open in the Spotify App") to app?

Example 1: https://open.spotify.com/artist/6vWDO969PvNqNYHIOW5v0m
After clicking the Spotify link, I'm redirected to Safari. After scrolling down the Safari page, I see the message "Spotify Music Open in the Spotify app" with the button "Open." After clicking "Open," I'm redirected to the Spotify app. Subsequent clicking of the Spotify link results in the same flow: My app --> Safari --> Click "Open" --> Spotify. I'm not being redirected directly from my app to the Spotify app

Example 2: https://urlgeni.us/spotify/Arty
After clicking the urlgeni Spotify link, I'm redirected to Safari. A message appears saying "Open this page in 'Spotify?'." After waiting a few seconds, I'm redirected to the Spotify app (Note: this is occurring without me clicking "Open".) 
Subsequent clicks to the urlgeni Spotify link has the same flow: My app --> Safari --> Spotify app

Comment: You should post the code you're having problems with.  It's not clear what question you're asking here.

Comment: @JJF It's not specifically with code, but more like I want to understand how Universal Links are supposed to behave. I edited my question to provide more context. Please me know if I should clarify anything. Thanks!

Comment: Is Spotify the app you want the link to open?

Comment: @theMikeSwan Yes, Spotify is just an example but it is the app I want to open if the user has Spotify installed

Comment: The examples you have added are not universal links they are web links that likely lead in turn to universal links so the user will _always_ go through Safari. A universal link would start with a different scheme (like `myApp://` rather than `https://`). If you want to go straight to Spotify you need to find out what custom URL scheme they use along with the proper format for the rest of the URL (they may not list this info as they may be collecting some analytics from the first link).

Comment: I thought that universal links are different from deep linking. Per https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html, universal links "Unlike custom URL schemes, universal links can’t be claimed by other apps, because they use standard HTTP or HTTPS links to your website."

Comment: That sounds right, I always forget what name they use for what. Maybe the Spotify app doesn't claim any domains? Or perhaps the database on your device dismissing that entry for some reason?

Comment: I also tried this with yelp as well and got the same behavior. I was just testing with apps that I thought supported universal links (http://www.jackivers.me/blog/2015/9/17/list-of-universal-link-ios-9-apps). I'm not sure if there is a way for me to verify that an app supports universal links other than it working lol. I did read somewhere that deep linking and universal links can be disabled easily without the users knowledge. But I'm not aware of how to reenable it.

Answer (score 0):

Directly to the app. No open app alert like in schemes.

[Here theres a u2 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ba2PfUkLhKw)

Comment: that has __published 2 years ago__... what was the last time you have touched iOS development?

Answer (score 0):

It should go app-to-app seamlessly - the `Open in 'Spotify'?` message you're getting should be a one time only flag, and afterwards subsequent Universal Links for Spotify will be app-to-app

Comment: With the example link https://urlgeni.us/spotify/Arty, the "Open in 'Spotify'?" isn't a one time flag. I'm seeing the flag each time I click the example link.